# FLASK PYTHON: Submitting a flask form not working

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make an upload form with Flask where the user needs to fill in the information needed, upload a photo, and also pick a category provided from the database by using QuerySelectField.

When I submit the form, nothing happens. It redirects me to the same page and the database is empty.

**form.py**

```
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
title = StringField(label='Title:', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=30)])
organizer = StringField(label='Name:', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=30)],
                        render_kw={'readonly': True})
type = QuerySelectField(query_factory=choice_query, allow_blank=False, get_label='name')
description = StringField(label='description',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=250)])
address = StringField(label='address',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=50)])
file = FileField(label='file', validators=[DataRequired()])
price = IntegerField(label='Price:', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=10)])
upload = SubmitField(label='Post')
```

**model.py**

```
class Event(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "event"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
location = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
description = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=True, unique=True)
date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
type = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True, default='default.jpg')
owner = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('eventowners.id'), nullable=False)
reserver = db.relationship('Reservation', foreign_keys=[Reservation.reserved_id],
                           backref=db.backref('reserved', lazy='joined'), lazy='dynamic',
                           cascade='all, delete-orphan')



class Choice(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "category"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
event = db.relationship('Event', backref='events', lazy=True)

def __repr__(self):
    return '[Choice {}]'.format(self.name)

class EventOwner(db.Model, UserMixin, USER):
__tablename__ = 'eventowners'
role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
sub_type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, default=00)
events = db.relationship('Event', backref='eventowner', lazy=True)
follower = db.relationship('Follow', foreign_keys=[Follow.followed_id],
                           backref=db.backref('followed', lazy='joined'), lazy='dynamic',
                           cascade='all, delete-orphan')
```

**routes.py**

```
@app.route('/event/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def post_events():
    if not os.path.exists('static/' + str(session.get('id'))):
       os.makedirs('static/' + str(session.get('id')))
    file_url = os.listdir('static/' + str(session.get('id')))
    file_url = [str(session.get('id')) + "/" +
                 file for file in file_url]
    formupload = UploadForm()
    eventowner = current_user.id
    formupload.organizer.data = eventowner
    event = Event(owner=formupload.organizer.data)
    if formupload.validate_on_submit():
       event = Event(title=formupload.title.data,
                  type=formupload.type.data,
                  description=formupload.description.data,
                  price=formupload.price.data,
                  location=formupload.address.data,
                  image_file=photos.save(formupload.file.data,
                                         name=str(session.get('id')) + '.jpg',))

      db.session.add(event)
      db.session.commit()
      flash('Event Posted!')
      return redirect(url_for('events_page'))
    return render_template('post_event.html', formupload=formupload, event=event)

@app.route('/event', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def events_page():
    event = Event.query.order_by(Event.date_posted.desc()).all()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    show_followed = False
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        show_followed = bool(request.cookies.get('show_followed', ''))
    if show_followed:
        query = current_user.followed_posts
    else:
        query = Event.query
    pagination = Event.query.order_by(Event.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page,
                                                                         per_page=
                                                                         current_app.config['FLASKY_POSTS_PER_PAGE'],
                                                                         error_out=False
                                                                         )
    events = pagination.items
    return render_template('event.html', events=events, pagination=pagination, show_followed=show_followed, event=event)
```

**post_event.html**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12">
                    <div class="breadcrumbs-content">
                        <h1 class="page-title">Events</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12">
                    <ul class="breadcrumb-nav">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li>Events</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
   {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <div class="search-form wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s" style="background: none; margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Title" style="color: black" >Event Title</label>
      {{ formupload.label }} {{ formupload.title(class='form-control' )}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="organizer" style="color: black" >Organizer</label>
     <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Organizer"> -->

      <div> {{ formupload.label }}  </div>
      <div> {{ formupload.organizer._value()}}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState" style="color: black" >Type</label>
          {{ formupload.csrf_token }}
          {{ formupload.type }}
          <ul>
            {% for error in formupload.type.errors %}
            <li style="color:red;">{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="description" style="color: black" >Description</label>
      {{ formupload.label }} {{ formupload.description(class='form-control' )}}
      <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="starting_price" style="color: black" >Starting Price</label>
      {{ formupload.label }} {{ formupload.price(class='form-control' )}}
      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Price"> -->
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress2" style="color: black" >Address</label>
       <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="Corso Duca degli Abruzzi, 24"> -->
        {{ formupload.label }} {{ formupload.address(class='form-control' )}}
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck" style="color: black">
          I agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ formupload.file.label }}
        {{ formupload.file }}
        {{ formupload.upload }}
        {% for file in filelist %}
            <img class="upload-img"  src='{{ url_for("static",filename=file) }}' alt="">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn--primary") }}
    </div>

  </div>
</form>

  {% include "bottom.html" %}

<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/wow.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/tiny-slider.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/glightbox.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do any functions get called? Have you set debug output or debugger breakpoints? Also, have you checked the logs?

Comment: I debugged it from the validations and everything seems to be working fine, it fills the form but for the Event model it says: Unable to get repr for <class 'website.model.Event'>

Comment: Search for that error message, maybe you find something. Even if not, add the full error message and where you get it to your question, so the next one having the same problem has a chance.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you're submitting a form via Javascript, a form submission will get sent to the value in `action` attribute of the form. Yours is blank which is why the page is simply reloaded.

`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">`

Update:

You need to specify a route in the action attribute e.g. `/event/new` or `/event` depending on which one is expected to process the form. If it's none of the above, then you have to define a route server side (your flask code) and specify the route in the action attribute.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Okay, thanks but still there isn't any value in my database. Do you have any idea?